# Why recursion is not handling state of variable

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree

This is a code to find all the paths of tree from root to leaf.
Input

[image]

```
class Node {
    constructor (val) {
        this.val   = val;
        this.left  = null;
        this.right = null; 
    }
}

const a = new Node('10');
const b = new Node('20');
const c = new Node('30');
const d = new Node('40');
const e = new Node('60');


a.left = b;
a.right = c;
b.left = d;
b.right = e;

function Paths(root){
        let paths = [];
        function traverse(node, path){
            if(!node){
                return;
            }
            path.push(node.val);
            if(node.left ==null && node.right ==null){
                paths.push(path.slice());
            }
            traverse(node.left,path);
            traverse(node.right,path);
            path.pop();
        }
        traverse(root,[]);
        console.log(paths);
        return paths;
    }
    Paths(a);
```

I know i need to backtrack so that i remove the last element (pop) and return to the original state.
But when I have shared **path** variable in recursive call shouldnt recursion handle itself what the value of path was when it was at specific node for example
for first path 10,20,40 when i move back to 20 again for right side of node shouldnt value of path variable be 10,20 at that time ?

vs we dont need any backtracking here
Given the root of a binary tree and an integer targetSum, return true if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals targetSum.

A leaf is a node with no children.

```
class Node {
    constructor (val) {
        this.val   = val;
        this.left  = null;
        this.right = null; 
    }
}

const a = new Node('1');
const b = new Node('2');
const c = new Node('3');
a.left = b;
a.right = c;


var hasPathSum = function(root, targetSum) {
    if(!root){
        return 0;
    }
    function dfs(node, currsum){
        if(!node){
            return false;
        }
        currsum+=Number(node.val);
        //
        if(node.left ==null && node.right ==null){
            return currsum == targetSum;
        }

        return dfs(node.left,currsum) || 
        dfs(node.right,currsum);
    }
    return dfs(root, 0);
};

let targetSum =31;
console.log(hasPathSum(a, targetSum));
```

Comment: I guess, you expect `path` to be a deep clone. It's not.

Comment: @jabaa why is behaviour different for second code i shared

Comment: You don't modify the variable in the second code (no `path.push`). `currsum` is a number.

Comment: currsum+=Number(node.val); , currsum is modified @jabaa

Comment: That's described in the dupe link. It's a difference whether you assign or modify.

Comment: @jabaa what does modify mean ?

Comment: Variables contain references to objects. An assignment changes the reference, but doesn't modify the object. A modification keeps the reference and modifies the object. It's all explained in detail in the link.

Comment: that explained @jabaa.thanks